# Is lm.morantest valid on residuals from geeglm fit of binary data?

Tags: logistic, autocorrelation, spatial

Is it valid to apply lm.morantest (in the package spdep) to test for spatial autocorrelation among residuals from a Generalized Explanatory Equation (geeglm in geepack) model fit of binary data? If not, is there another solution to test for residual spatial autocorrelation since Moran's is not appropriate for the binary raw response data either?